# Ruby on rails 3.2 accepts_nested_attributes validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am working on a ruby on rails 3.2 app and I need to validate a form with nested attributes. In my model I had this

```
class Member 
    attr_accessible :email, :password.............etc
    has_many :purchase_informations, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_informations, :allow_destroy => true
end

class PurchaseInformation 
    belongs_to :member
    attr_accessor :same_billing
end
```

and below is the form data:

```
{ members: 
     { purchase_informations_attributes: 
          { 0: 
               { information_type: "billing",
                 title: "Mr",
                 first_name: "",
                 last_name: "",
                 cuhk_no: "",
                 organization: "",
                 address: "",
                 zip_code: "",
                 country: "Hong Kong",
                 telephone: "",
                 mobile: "", fax: "",
                 email: "asdasdasda", id: "27"
              },
           1: 
              { information_type: "shipping",
                title: "Mr",
                first_name: "",
                last_name: "",
                cuhk_no: "",
                organization: "",
                address: "",
                zip_code: "",
                country: "Hong Kong",
                telephone: "",
                mobile: "",
                fax: "",
                email: "",
                id: "28"
              }
         }
     } 
}
```

Please help me out to validate if the attributes are blanks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try this:

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for : purchase_informations, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

or in your form put a :required => true function

```
<%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
```

Comment: Hi Allen. Thanks for your insight, unfortunately above method is not an option since I need to iterate through each values to check if there is blank values. It will only work if all values are blank. For the required attribute on the input field, this is used on html 5 and not all browsers support this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this: this validates for a specific column and validates presence of a name for a nested attribute:
accepts_nested_attributes_for : purchase_informations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[: name].blank? }